# How could I install sbt plugin globally

Tags: android, plugins, sbt

I have android-sdk-plugin downloaded from github. Documentation says that I need to install plugin globally:

> Install the plugin globally into ~/.sbt/plugins or ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins (for 0.12 and 0.13, respectively)
>   addSbtPlugin("com.hanhuy.sbt" % "android-sdk-plugin" % "1.3.18")

But I just don't understand what should I do... just copy all cloned files of plugin to ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins ? I know that's a simple question but there is lack of documentation about global plugins and I have no idea how to do it.
This is a source https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin/blob/master/README.md#usage

Comment: Now that you have your question answered you could use github to edit the README.md to clarify this sections by proposing a file change and then doing a pull request to pfn's repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to create a file in the `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins` directory, for instance:

**~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/android.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.hanhuy.sbt" % "android-sdk-plugin" % "1.3.18")
```

Answer (score 1):

As Dale Wijnand said we need to place *.sbt file into ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/ directory. But also we have to run 'sbt publishLocal' in order to be able to reference from that file to plugin's sources. And then run 'sbt reload' for changes to take effect.