# Run sbt plugin not in build.sbt

Tags: sbt, sbt-plugin

I am trying to write an SBT plugin for an IDE to query for information like the source path.  Using maven, I would do something like

```
mvn my.org:myPlugin:myGoal
```

This works, even if the `pom.xml` does not reference the plugin.  Is there a similar way to do this with `sbt`?

Getting the source path is an example.  I know that I can do that with `sbt show sourceDirectories`, but that is not a good answer for two reasons:

1. I want to be able to use the same interface for `mvn` and `sbt`, plus any additional build tools that are supported in the future, which involves starting a process to repsond to queries
2. I am looking for more than just the source path

Is it possible to start my plugin without having the user add it to build.sbt (or install it globally)?  Or is there a better way to run a jar from a remote repository (not mentioned in build.sbt)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could I install sbt plugin globally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29301865/how-could-i-install-sbt-plugin-globally)